# How can I make the columns at joomla frontpage to work?

Tags: joomla, frontpage

I am currently developing a website in joomla, all tho I have learned a lot there is this thing I wanted a help:

I wanted to know how can i make the columns to work at joomla frontpage, if I go to Main Menu-> Home-> Parameters (Basic) and set intro to '6' and columns to 2, I don't get results from the articles, they are still in the same way as before, not even if I post another articles it works, how can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you cleaned your Joomla cache?

Comment: Whats that? where i go to do that

Comment: sorry for delay. All depend of your Joomla version. Check links in your backend: system/delete cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by studying the template and re-creating a joomla frontpage, after that i could set the columns by geting CSS height and width in dpi and editing then on the module properties